# Google Glass extra.PHONE_NUMBER ignoring country code

Tags: android, android-intent, google-glass

I am writing an App for Google Glass and when using the Intent

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent();
localIntent.putExtra("com.google.glass.extra.PHONE_NUMBER", "+4123456789");
localIntent.setAction("com.google.glass.action.CALL_DIAL");
sendBroadcast(localIntent);
```

Where +41 is the country code for Switzerland and (0)23 the area code for a city, my phone just calls the number 023456789.
With a country code from germany and a mobile number it works perfectly. 
Why is that and is there a way to get the phone to call the right number?

EDIT: Still having the same issue. With a swiss phone, the call to a swiss number works, but it seems like sometimes the country code is left out. When using an austrian phone-number, the country code is submitted to the phone and used.

Thank you